# Access 2013, Append & Update query changes primary key which I would like to remain static

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables that need to have an append and update query run regularly. Each time I run these queries they cause the receiving table to begin numbering where the new records left off. How can I get tbl1 to increment up from 1 by ones and tbl2 to increment up from 1000000 by ones even after the update/append?

The PK I'm using it the default auto number field.

tbl1: Updated by local users in real time

tbl2: Imported copy of tbl1, remote users download it, work off of it then update tbl1 using the update and append queries below.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 ( Field1, Field2 )
SELECT tbl2.Field1, tbl2.Field2
From tbl2;

UPDATE tbl2
INNER JOIN tbl1
ON tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID 
SET tbl1.Field1 = IIf([tbl2].[Field1] Is Null,[tbl1].[Field1],[tbl2].[Field1]), 
tbl1.Field2 = IIf([tbl2].[Field2] Is Null,[tbl1].[Field2],[tbl2].[Field2])
;
```

I have the remote users each assigned a PK seed number far enough apart that they will never overlap.

```
ALTER TABLE Table ALTER COLUMN Field COUNTER(1000000,1);

ALTER TABLE Table ALTER COLUMN Field COUNTER(2000000,1);
```

Comment: Why do you believe that `UPDATE` query changes values in your primary key field?  Isn't `ID` the primary key for `tbl2`?  If not, which field is its primary key?

Comment: ID is the primary for both. It looks like  the append query is changing the numbering on me. At the moment a command button uses a macro to run both at the same time. So I'm trying to work that Alter Table query in after the Append in the Macro.

Comment: I think you may need a different strategy here.  For the moment, accept there is a way to preserve the *tbl2.ID* values when you append to *tbl1*.  That could be enough if you never add new rows directly to *tbl1* again and expect their new autonumber *ID* values to resume from the old series of values (the lower number range).  The reason those new autonumbers would not continue from the old series is that the append query causes Access to reset *tbl1's* autonumber seed value to one more than the largest *ID* value in the table.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: What other strategy do you suggest? -Thank you-

Comment: I not sure TBH.  Perhaps a composite key based on an origin field and a custom autonumber field.